# Spivak Caculus chapter 9 problem 27, about Derivatives and Induction

Tags: derivatives, induction

Problem 27 states:
If $S_n(x)=x^n$, and $0\le k\le n$, prove that:
$$S_n^{(k)}(x)=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}x^{n-k}$$

The answer book says:

Proof by induction on k. The result is true for $k=0$. If
$$S^{(k)}(x)=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}x^{n-k}$$

then $$\quad\quad\quad S_n^{(k+1)}(x)=\frac{n!(n-k)}{(n-k)!}x^{n-k-1}\quad\quad\require{enclose}\enclose{circle}{1}$$
$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\,\, =\frac{n!}{[n-(k+1)]!}x^{n-(k+1)}$$
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I feel some process is missing in $\require{enclose}\enclose{circle}{1}$. I know it's true, because previous exercise asked to prove: $$ if:\quad S_m(x)=x^m, \quad\quad then:\quad S^{'}_m(x)=mx^{m-1}$$ Let $m=n-k$, is it sufficient to say "Rising $x$ to $-1$ power will multiply $n-k$ on its left." for $\mathbf {any\,\; higher-order}$ derivative?

Another question, should the induction require the result to be true for $k=1$,but not $k=0$?

I know the answer is right, but I missed something here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The idea is not to raise $x$ to $-1$. If you differentiate $x^{n-k}$, what you get is $(n-k)x^{n-k-1}$. That's all that is needed (and all that is used).

And the induction proof starts by proving that the statement holds when $k=0$. The other step is to prove that if it holds for a cetain $k$, it also holds for $k+1$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got the first question. but still not sure if $k=0$ is proved it.
The text says: 1 is in A, and k+1 is in A whenever k is in A.

Comment: That identity, with $k=0$, is just $S_n(x)=\frac{n!}{(n-0))!}x^{n-0}$. Since $\frac{n!}{(n-0))!}x^{n-0}=x^n$, it is a trivial assertion.